# Oracle Select JOIN Listagg. Duplicates in the output. Using Distinct or other

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have been working on this query to between two tables (one to many) and append all the fields together into one string using LISTAGG. I noticed that the outputs have duplicates values and I found that there are duplicates records in the table. How do I use distinct or another technique to remove the duplicate.

Here is my query

```
SELECT Table2.PersonId, 
LISTAGG(case Table2.BookTitleDesc 
        when 'Value1' then '1'
            when Value2' then '2'
            when 'Value3' then '3'
            when 'Value4' then '4'

 end, ':') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Table2.BookTitleDesc )  
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.PersonId = Table2.PersonId
GROUP BY Table2.PERSON_ID
```

I am getting output like 1:1:2:3:4. Ideally the BookTitleDesc should be unique but the tables has dups. In my CASE.. WHEN statement, it will be really long. I 
have a lot to filter and I saw there were many dups. How can I use DISTINCT or some other technique to avoid dups in my output?

Thanks

Comment: Posting some sample data (preferably in the form of "create table" and "insert" statements, or perhaps "create table ... as (select ...)") will help forum members understand your question and test their proposed answers.

Comment: Looking at your query, you would get 1:1:2:3:4 only if the way you assign values in your CASE expression is "in alphabetical order" (that is, if 'Value1', 'Value2', ... are already sorted alphabetically). Is that the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just run it through a SELECT DISTINCT before aggregating?

```
SELECT s.PersonId, 
LISTAGG(case s.BookTitleDesc 
        when 'Value1' then '1'
            when 'Value2' then '2'
            when 'Value3' then '3'
            when 'Value4' then '4'

 end, ':') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.BookTitleDesc )  
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Table2.PersonId,
        Table2.BookTitleDesc
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 
    ON Table1.PersonId = Table2.PersonId
    ) s
GROUP BY s.PERSON_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

LISTAGG aggregated function doesn't have an option for removing duplicates, so you have to remove them first.

In the following code Table2_ND will be Table2 with no duplicates, essentially same idea as Bacon Bits using the "WITH" syntactic sugar.

```
WITH Table2_ND AS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table2)
SELECT   Table2_ND.PersonId
        ,LISTAGG(
            CASE Table2_ND.BookTitleDesc 
              WHEN 'Value1' THEN '1' 
              WHEN 'Value2' THEN '2' 
              WHEN 'Value3' THEN '3' 
              WHEN 'Value4' THEN '4' 
            END, ':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Table2_ND.BookTitleDesc)
FROM     Table1 INNER JOIN Table2_ND ON Table1.PersonId = Table2_ND.PersonId
GROUP BY Table2_ND.PersonId, Table2.BookTitleDesc;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Oracle sql (I think from version 19c) there is listagg distinct:

```
select listagg(distinct ID, ', ') from TAB_1 t1 inner join TAB_2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.TAB1_ID;
```

This will give you only distinct Id's